# Can subclass inherit type property from its super class? And if yes, how to override it?

Tags: ios, inheritance, properties, swift3, overriding

[code running in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unEV3.png)

“For computed type properties for class types, you can use the class keyword instead to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation.”

“You can override an inherited instance or type property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that property”
                                                        ----Apple Swift3

```
//override static
class A{
    var myValue = 0614
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value"
    class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
        return 1
    }
}
class B: A {
    storedTypeProperty = "New String"
}
```

It seems like that B doesn't inherit any type property from A.
So how to override the "inherited type property" as described above in Swift3 book.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? You can't override `static` property, but you can do that with other variables.

Comment: I don't understand what those two sentences mean as mentioned in Swift3. It says that you can override an inherited type property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is because you are using a `static` variable. `static` variables can not be overwritten, full stop. No point to argue here.

First sentence says, if you have a `class` (not a `struct`),like `class A {}` , you can use the `class` keyword instead of the `static` keyword, and override class types. This means, that you can use two keyword for the same purpose, with a major difference, that `static` can not be overwritten.

```
class A {
    // overridable computed property
    class var overridableClassPropery: String {
        return "This is class A's overwritten property" 
    }

    // Not overridable `static` computed property
    // Error will be shown if you try to override this property in class `B`
    static var notOverridableStaticPropery: String {
        return "Can not override this property in a subclass"
    }
}
```

The second one says, that you can override a superclasses class property, and provide your own `get` implementation in a subclass, like the following:

```
  class B: A {
    // Class type computed property can be overwritten
    override class var overridableClassPropery: String {
        return "This is class B's overwritten property"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

`notOverridableStaticPropery` of `class A` is being inherited by `class B`, what means, you  can access / call it through `class B`. **BUT** you can not override it, it will have the value set in `class A` always.

```
print(A.notOverridableStaticPropery) // prints "This is class A's not overridable static property"
print(B.notOverridableStaticPropery) // prints "This is class A's not overridable static property"
```

Comment: Ok, there's still one point I don't understand that in the second sentence, it mentioned  "inherited type property", so, B should inherit the type property "notOverridableStaticProperty" from A, but I can't call this type property on B, what have I missed?